# Sub-select with a variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I have a `ul` with a series of `li` in it.

I store the `ul` as a JQuery variable, like so `var myUl = $("ul")`

Now I want to select all the `li` contained in `myUl`.

Now, I realize that in this specific example I could do, `$(myUl).children();` but I'm wondering how I could do something like this: `$(myUl + "li")` and have it work? What's the syntax for combining a variable and other text?

Or do I have to make a new variable that says `var newUl = $("ul li")`?

Comment: I think it would help if you explain what you're trying to do in a real usage scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the `myUl` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) in the selector.

```
$("li", myUl)
```

Sample [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/9mSCQ/1/)

To quote the docs

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, 
>   so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" ).

In other words, passing the context to the selector is the same as doing `myUl.find('li')`

Answer (score 6):

```
myUl.find("li");
```

or

```
myUl.children("li");
```

`find` will get all descendants whereas `children` is just direct children.

Answer (score 1):

So I just learned you can actually use variables in this manner:

http://jsfiddle.net/VMM4x/

```
<ul id="myUl">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>there</li>
</ul

var ul = $('#myUl');
var li = $('li', ul);
li.each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

To be clear, this searches for li tags under the `var ul` object.